# How to render the route component based on the response from an api?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

Consider we have to pass additional props to the routes,which we get from an api.How can we do that?

Answer (score -1):

In root.js, fire the network call,and assign the response to the state of the Root component which in turn will re render the component.Now pass the response as prop to the routes component.Now use the response to dynamically generate routes.

You can pass now the required parameters to `<Route>` and render the UI